# A List of 3D numpy array iteration through all elements with nditer() from numpy 1.15.3

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, for-loop, iteration

I have a list of 3D Numpy Arrays and I want to iterate each element of this structure and make some changes with if statemets. The code below performs what I want to do:

```
for counter1, entry in enumerate(all_frames_flow):
    for counter2, entry2 in enumerate(entry):
        for counter3, entry3 in enumerate(entry2):
            for counter4, entry4 in enumerate(entry3):
                if entry4 < -20.0:
                    all_frames_flow[counter1][counter2][counter3][counter4]=-20.0
                if entry4 > 20.0:
                    all_frames_flow[counter1][counter2][counter3][counter4]=20.0
                all_frames_flow[counter1][counter2][counter3][counter4]/=20
```

But I was wondering if there is a more pythonic way. In `numpy >=1.15.0` I tried this new code from documentation but it fails, it doesn't give back the results I want, I can see values greater than `abs(20)` and I wonder why is that:

```
for counteref, _ in enumerate(backup2):                    
    with np.nditer(backup2[counteref], op_flags=['readwrite'], order = 'K') as it:
            for x in it:
                #print x
                if (x < -20.0):
                    x=-20.0
                if (x > 20.0):
                    x = 20.0
                x/=20.0
```

Comment: `nditer` is tricky to use, and usually not faster or (this elusively defined) pythonic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before trying better/alternate iterators, you should try to do the task without iteration (that is do things with compiled `numpy` code)

```
In [347]: arr = np.random.randint(-40,40,(2,3,4))
```

For example, there's a `clip` method:

```
In [348]: arr.clip(-20, 20)
Out[348]: 
array([[[-20, -20,  20,  -6],
        [-15, -17,  -8, -20],
        [  2, -20, -16,  20]],

       [[-20,   3, -20,  17],
        [ 20,  20,  20, -17],
        [ 11, -20,  20,   0]]])
```

and dividing everything by 20 is trivial in `numpy`:

```
In [349]: _/20
Out[349]: 
array([[[-1.  , -1.  ,  1.  , -0.3 ],
        [-0.75, -0.85, -0.4 , -1.  ],
        [ 0.1 , -1.  , -0.8 ,  1.  ]],

       [[-1.  ,  0.15, -1.  ,  0.85],
        [ 1.  ,  1.  ,  1.  , -0.85],
        [ 0.55, -1.  ,  1.  ,  0.  ]]])
```

Better yet, learn to do this sort of thing with boolean masking:

```
In [351]: arr
Out[351]: 
array([[[-32, -30,  39,  -6],
        [-15, -17,  -8, -34],
        [  2, -31, -16,  35]],

       [[-39,   3, -37,  17],
        [ 31,  30,  28, -17],
        [ 11, -24,  26,   0]]])

In [354]: mask1 = arr<-20
In [355]: mask2 = arr>20
In [356]: mask1
Out[356]: 
array([[[ True,  True, False, False],
        [False, False, False,  True],
        [False,  True, False, False]],

       [[ True, False,  True, False],
        [False, False, False, False],
        [False,  True, False, False]]])
In [357]: mask2
Out[357]: 
array([[[False, False,  True, False],
        [False, False, False, False],
        [False, False, False,  True]],

       [[False, False, False, False],
        [ True,  True,  True, False],
        [False, False,  True, False]]])
In [358]: arr[mask1]=-20
In [359]: arr[mask2]=20
In [360]: arr
Out[360]: 
array([[[-20, -20,  20,  -6],
        [-15, -17,  -8, -20],
        [  2, -20, -16,  20]],

       [[-20,   3, -20,  17],
        [ 20,  20,  20, -17],
        [ 11, -20,  20,   0]]])
```

---

As for your iteration, it's important to remember that in any Python iteration you can't use

for x in ...:
      x=-20.0

to modify the source.  That `x=...` assignment assigns a new value to the `x` variable, and breaks its link with the iteration.  Try that with a simple list if you don't see why.  You have to mutate the variable in-place.  If `x` is simple integer that isn't possible.

In your first iteration you are indexing and mutating `all_frames_flow`, so it works:

all_frames_flow[counter1][counter2, counter3, counter4]=-20.0

`nditer` does provide a mutable iteration variable, so you can do:

```
In [364]: with np.nditer(arr, op_flags=['readwrite'], order = 'K') as it:
     ...:    for x in it:
     ...:        #print x
     ...:        if (x < -20.0):
     ...:            x[...]=-20.0      # change x in-place
     ...:        if (x > 20.0):
     ...:            x[...] = 20.0
     ...:
```

All the `nditer` examples that change values should be using this `[...]=` notation.

I don't encourage the use of `nditer`, at least not Python code.  In Python code it's most useful as a way of testing ideas that will be implemented in your own compiled code (with `cython`).  It doesn't offer any speed advantages.

Comment: but which of all is faster at execution though ?

Comment: There are tools for timing executions.

Comment: last line should be x[...]/=20.0 , right ? or x/=20 ?

Comment: If dividing all `x /= 20` is right.  `x[...] /=` works, but isn't needed.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer *numpy.ndindex* to save myself some nested loops and keep the function structure reasonable flat. I have the feeling that *numpy.nditer* is more useful for cases with more arrays to loop over:

```
mat = np.random.rand(2, 3, 4) * 100 - 50
for i in np.ndindex(*mat.shape):
    if mat[i] < -20:
        mat[i] = -20
    if mat[i] > 20:
        mat[i] = 20  
mat /= 20.0
```

An alternative is to use *numpy.where* for conditions and operations, that do not depend on the specific index but apply for the whole array:

```
mat = np.random.rand(2, 3, 4) * 100 - 50
#              Condition, if True, if False
mat = np.where(mat < -20,     -20,     mat)
mat = np.where(mat > +20,      20,     mat)
mat /= 20.0
```

And for your specific case of clipping the values of an array outside a defined range *numpy.clip(arr, a_min, a_max)* is probably the easiest and fastest way.

Comment: `ndindex` is one of the few pieces of interpreted `numpy` code that uses `np.nditer`.